# Is Font Squirrel for real?

Tags: fonts

I found [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/), and while it claims to have fonts free for commercial use, i can't find a license or legal pages anywhere. Are these fonts really usable for commecial use like they say?

Comment: This looks like great resource.  Now if only I could get my in game font rendering to not suck so bad.

Comment: FYI, some of their fonts require attribution for commercial use. Just saying. Make sure you cite it appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I would get them from the sites of the people that they are credited to. I say this because I see a font that I use (Museo) and I know that the font is free, but when compared to the license given at the Font Squirrel site it is different (and kind of unclear) than the one on the creators site.</strike>

Checked a few more and the licenses seem alright. But I still recommend cross-refrencing the license available at the original creator's sites just to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really think they could say, in very large print on the home screen:

> Only the best commercial- use free fonts
>
> Free fonts have met their match. We
>   know how hard it is to find quality
>   freeware that is licensed for
>   commercial work.

If they weren't.

Comment: Ya never know...